# React Native FlatList keyExtractor "Item undefined" on Android

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-flatlist

I have a simple FlatList that works when testing in the web browser, but on Android it gives an error

> "TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'item.id')"

```
<FlatList       
    data={data}
    renderItem={renderItem}
    keyExtractor={item => item.id}
/>
```

Putting a console log in the keyExtractor confirms that the `item` parameter is undefined, but only on Android. I've tried using the `(item, index) => index.toString()` as the extractor, the index parameter is correct but it also gives an error
The data list is this

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "item1",
        "sku": "001",
        "price": 0,
        "quantity": 0
    }
]
```

Here's the render item function

```
const renderItem = ({item}) => {
    return <InventoryItem item={item}/>
};
```

Comment: If you has an `id` key in the objects of your data array, you dont necessarily to use the `keyExtractor` .. your data comes from a fetch or is it just a mock?

Comment: If I don't include the keyExtractor, it still has item undefined but in the built in keyExtractor. The data is from a fetch

Comment: Ok, might its because your data isn't still loaded, you need to render a loading component until you get the data, your loading component can be a custom component or `<ActivityIndicator />` from react-native.. so yo'll have `data ? <FlatList .../> : <ActivityIndicator />`

Comment: I kind of already have that 
`return (data.length > 0)? ( <FlatList .../> ):( <Message data={message}/> );`
The data is set with a useState

Comment: Mmmh, if you log `data` it has the correct structure right?.. I don't know if you use the `item.id` inside `InventoryItem` too

Comment: Yes, `data` has the correct structure, I do use `item.id` inside `InventoryItem`.

Comment: well, a quick solution can be use the optional chaining inside your InventoryItem `item?.id` , but if you want to share the code of InventoryItem might we give you a better solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, the database connection uses slightly different syntax on Android than it does on web